# error al implementar array numpy en una función de Flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask, tensorflow, nltk

estoy tratando de ejecutar el entrenamiento de una IA atreves de una función con Flask.
esta función debe ser capas de ejecutarse cada vez que yo haga clic en un botón de HTML.
El problema que tengo es que al darle clic el código me da un error, para ser específicos es este error

**ValueError: establecer un elemento de matriz con una secuencia. La matriz solicitada tiene una forma no homogénea después de 2 dimensiones. La forma detectada fue (6, 2) + parte no homogénea.**

Que sucede justo en esta lineal de código:

**training = np.array(training)**

siempre me da el mismo error, pero al ejecutarlo fuera de una función este corre perfecto.

ya no se que puedo hacer, eh averiguado por todos lados, pero al parecer me cuenta encontrar algo especifico para este tema.

Mi código complote es este:

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import login_required

import json
import random
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

trainingBP = Blueprint('trainingBP', __name__)

@trainingBP.route("/entrenar", methods = ['POST'])
@login_required
def entrenar():
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('wordnet')

    words = []
    classes = []
    documents = []
    ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '¿', '.', ',']

    for intent in intents['intents']:
        for pattern in intent['patterns']:
            word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(word_list)
            documents.append((word_list, intent["tag"]))
            if intent["tag"] not in classes:
                classes.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
    words = sorted(set(words))

    pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
    pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

    training = []
    output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

    for document in documents:
        bag = []
        word_patterns = document[0]
        word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
        for word in words:
            bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)
        output_row = list(output_empty)
        output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
        training.append([bag, output_row])

    random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(training[0][0]),)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(len(training[0][1])))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(training)

    train_x = list(training[:,0])
    train_y = list(training[:,1])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))


    optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    train_process = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=1)

    model.save("chatbot_model.h5", train_process)

    return redirect(url_for('home_admin'))
```

¿Cómo podre solucionarlo? He cambiado el código varias veces, incluso lo e encapsulado en una clase con funciones y luego la llamo desde el route pero me da el mismo error

estoy usando un Json para asignar los parámetros con los que debe entrenar, todo esto funciona perfecto. Además si pruebo el código solo en un archivo de Python normal sin funciones ni Flask, este funciona de lo mas bien

soy nuevo en esto de las ia y python ¿Alguna ayuda?